# Turn a multi-hop ssh connection into a direct connection

Tags: networking, ssh, nat

I have a machine behind a NAT (that I don't control) that has a reverse SSH connection to a home machine. I can then ssh into my home machine, and via the open reverse connection to the NAT'd machine, I can make a second hop resulting in a connection from my laptop, to home, to the NAT'd machine.

However, this setup is incredibly inefficient. Even trying to use Vim on the NAT'd machine through the double SSH connection is sad and laggy.

My question is whether I can somehow turn this double-hop into a direct connection after I establish the original connection?  Somehow video games manage to make these direct connections behind a NAT with [TCP hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching), the workings of which I'm not familiar with.

Is this thing practical in any way? Is it even technically feasible?

Comment: The larger question is why you believe that two SSH hops will somehow be faster if it is only on SSH hop? Yeah, it sounds like—in theory—one hop would be more efficient but honestly two hops is no big deal. The issue is more likely that simply SSHing into that network is inefficient for reasons you most likely cannot control.

Comment: @JakeGould I think that what you are saying is true.  However, I'm pretty sure that SSHing into the *intermediate* machine is the slow connection.  The middleman only exists so that the two machines (the one I'm on and the one I want access to) can talk to begin with.  Unfortunately, my home internet is pretty sub-par, and piping everything through that network is a bottleneck.

Comment: Well, if that is the case best of luck on this. I know how SSHing into a slow system can be.